# Right click-running a single Cucumber scenario in IntelliJ with hard braces in the title causes nothing to be run

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, scenarios

I'm using IntelliJ with the Java Cucumber plugin. The right click -> "Run 'Scenario: ..." feature works great - except when there are hard braces in the Scenario name. An example

```
Scenario Outline: The user tries to access a hyperlink referring to a page inside the application without being logged in [JIRA Number]
```

In this case, when running it in the way described above, I will get:

```
None of the features at 
[C:/dev/git_repositories/myapp.git/test/Cuke-Test/src/test/resources/com/maven/test/Login.feature] 
matched the filters: 
[The user tries to access a hyperlink 
referring to a page inside the application 
without being logged in [JIRA Number]]





0 scenario (0 passed)


0 steps (0 passed)


0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0,000s
```

Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.

I noticed that if there is soft braces, ( and ), in the scenario name, they will be escaped in the output, like \( and \).

The obvious solution is of course to not have hard braces in the scenario names :] But what if that's just how it's done in the team I'm working with? How do I fix it so that it works?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Cucumber integration. Please report it as an issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Comment: On your recommendation, I did: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142213